# How to Localize NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key (ALAssets)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, alassetslibrary

I'm trying to localize the *NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription* key defined in the application's info.plist file ([reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)).
This key gives you a point to provide custom message when the app is first asking for access to your camera roll.
I'm using ALAssetsLibrary to enumerate assets groups (which triggers the access request message to pop-up).

So far my googling doesn't answer how I could achieve this.

I want to avoid localizing the whole info.plist file as it contain a lot more non-locale dependent content.

Anyone already solved this or have hints how to proceed?

Comment: "So far my googling doesn't answer how I could achieve this." And now my Googling brought me here, thanks for asking this!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is a file you can create (which may be created for you when you create a project) called `InfoPlist.strings`.  This file is used and localized much like the file `Localizable.strings`.

In it you would have and entry something like:

```
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription = "Test of new Photos warnings";
```

Note that there are no quotation marks around the key

I think as long as the key is included in `info.plist`, it will localized using the value in `InfoPlist.string` if it is available for the language.  Otherwise it will use whatever is defined in info.plist.

Comment: Thank you Joe! :) Perfectly working. Once I got the keyword "InfoPlist" i found [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) in Apple docs. Hope this could be helpful to other people too! Regs.

Comment: FWIW it didn't work for me until I wrapped NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in  double quotes, too.

Comment: If localized, what should the key's value contain in the plist file?

Comment: @lulian, The localized key's value contains the text string, translated into whatever language you are localizing.

Comment: To be clear: the line above "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" = "..."; needs to be in both the main "Info.plist" file aswell as the localized "InfoPlist.string" files.

Answer (score 3):

I have my note here https://github.com/onmyway133/notes/issues/290, or you will get

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>   Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Make sure

- You declare the keys in Info.plist
- You localize it in InfoPlist.strings
- You don't need double quotes, like `"NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" = "Test of new Photos warnings";`, you can just use `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription = "Test of new Photos warnings";`

Comment: It's not fully clear to me what `You declare the keys in Info.plist` means. Does this mean, just put the `<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>` part without the following `<string>This app requires access to the camera</string>` part?

Comment: Looks like declare means to redundantly give the key and value in both places. At least for your "primary" language.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to make this work for me was in Xcode to:

1) Go to `Project target -> Info-> Localization-> Add localization`

Added language there. This operation created the `<projectName>/<LanguageInitials>.lproj` folder.

[image]

2) I created file InfoPlist.strings inside the folder `<projectName>/<LanguageInitials>.lproj`;

3) I added the text:

`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription = "<Add your translated text here>";`

inside that `InfoPlist.strings` file.

4) I then added that folder to the project with `File -> add new files to the project` or drag and drop.

Note: to test this I:

Cleaned cache, set the language on simulator to be the new one, edited the language in scheme to be the new one at running on simulator and restarted the simulator.

[image]

Comment: Did that and worked very welll, thx!