# iTunes connect rejects my App after uploading because of missing privacy-access descriptions

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, xcode8

I want to upload my app to iTunes connect but after uploading I always get an error message by mail from iTunes, that after their scan some description variables are missing.

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I am using both features, so that's ok, BUT: i already added those variables to my localized `infoPlist.strings`. And these seems to work, because in the Simulator and my iPhone, both strings are displayed correctly in the system dialogs. I didn't add the strings to the `plist.info` file, because I specified them in the localized file, which should be ok. The plist.info and also the localized file are both packaged in the app, I already head a look using Finder.

Is there anything else I must add? Do I still need to add them to the `plist.info` file, although they are in the localized file?

Additional info: I am using the latest XCode 8 GM build on macOS Safari.

Comment: please check this link and try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881534/how-to-localize-nsphotolibraryusagedescription-key-alassets

Comment: [refer this so post if it helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428916/uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift-3/39429884#39429884)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will add those keys to the plist.info and will give feedback if this helps. And if the localization still works with the localized keys and the keys in the plist.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is, to add the keys also to the PList.info file, not only to the localized infoPlist.strings file.
This is a bit inconsequent because within the simulator and on my phone every message is displayed correctly. But now my app was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using AdMob? If so the answer is that Google confirmed that it is an issue with the AdMob SDK. You can read about it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ios/y-IxErXawxg).